# Html.ActionLink() having the hyperlink underline when mouse over or clicked

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, w3.css

Please how can i make use of the html.actionlink() without having the String LinkText Underlined.

Below is the HTML

```
<div class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-opacity">
        <i class="fa fa-home w3-xlarge">
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { onclick="showSpinner()"})
        </i>
    </div>
```

Comment: Make a css class and set `text-decoration: none;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using style overloaded version of `Html.ActionLink`

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "Action name", "Controller name", new { area = "" }, new { Style = "text-decoration:none;"})
```